# onDateSet interface getting a stack overflow error

Tags: java, android, android-dialogfragment, android-datepicker

I have a separate java file:

```
public class DatePickerDialogFragment extends DialogFragment implements DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener {

    @Override
    public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Use the current date as the default date in the picker
        final Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
        int year = c.get(Calendar.YEAR);
        int month = c.get(Calendar.MONTH);
        int day = c.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);

        // Create a new instance of DatePickerDialog and return it
        return new DatePickerDialog(getActivity(), this, year, month, day);
    }

    public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int years, int month, int day) {
        // Do something with the date chosen by the user
        onDateSet(view, years, month, day);
    }
}
```

In my MainActivity I have:

```
public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity implements OnDateSetListener{
...
    @Override
    public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int year, int monthOfYear, int dayOfMonth) {
        this.year = year;
        this.month = monthOfYear;
        this.day = dayOfMonth;

    }
}
```

I get stackOverflow on

```
onDateSet(view, years, month, day);
```

in my DialogFragment when I press the "Done" button on the fragment.

Logcat:

```
03-30 23:42:30.231: E/AndroidRuntime(4226): java.lang.StackOverflowError
03-30 23:42:30.231: E/AndroidRuntime(4226):     at com.myapp.example.gui.dialogfragments.DatePickerDialogFragment.onDateSet(DatePickerDialogFragment.java:27)
03-30 23:42:30.231: E/AndroidRuntime(4226):     at com.myapp.example.gui.dialogfragments.DatePickerDialogFragment.onDateSet(DatePickerDialogFragment.java:27)
```

Comment: So have you created an instance of your fragment and set it?

Comment: I add my fragment as a dialogFragmnet.

Comment: Ok, please share the logcat so I can see what error is being printed!

Comment: @EGHDK In `onDateSet` you call  `onDateSet(view, years, month, day);`. Its a recursive call leading to stackvoerflowerror. just follow the link i posted in your previous question. it will work